# finding best route under constraint with changing constraints

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, scheduling

I am trying to solve the following problem:

- a car travels from a destination to another
- we are trying to reach point B from point A
- the destinations are graphs of locations with the duration (in hours) of the route from start to destination on each vertex
- at each possible hour, events "E" can be at any location. This is known in advance. For instance: at destination D1 there will be an event at hour h=0, h=1, h=4. Same for other destinations for instance.
- we are trying to reach a point to B from point A such that it encounters a minimal number of events. ie we trying to avoid arriving at a place where an "event" will be at this time
- we don't actually care about the total duration of the trip, as long as it is less than a given total time (eg 100 hours)
- we can wait in place at the same place for however long

I'm able to solve this using Dynamic Programming, but it seems that the complexity for this is quite big, as at each possible destination I'm testing all other possible destinations as the next step, *plus* all the possible waiting time in place (eg, going to town D after waiting 1 hour, going to town D after waiting 2 hours, etc).

Is there a smarter way to solve this? The fact that the "events" have no particular structure makes it hard I think.
Ideally, I'd first find out all the possible routes from A to B, and somehow add the knowledge of events afterward

Comment: What needs to be minimised? The duration or the number of events? If both, then you must specify some trade-off.

Comment: @trincot the number of events

Comment: So a path of 100 hops (hours) without events is better than a path with 2 steps with one event, right?

Comment: @trincot indeed !